# Is there an easy convertor between dpkg --print-architecture and uname -m for generic scp?

Tags: printing, cpu, scp, cp

I want to copy files that relevant to my machines (x86_64 / aarch64) from remote machines.
I want to use: `scp user@host:*$(uname)* .` to copy both wheels and .deb files, e.g.:

1. name-x.y.z-cp36-cp36m-linux_x86_64.whl
2. name_x.y.z_amd64.deb

Now, using `$(uname -m)` will yield `x86_64` which matches the wheel, and using `$(dpkg --print-architecture) will yield` amd64` which matches the .deb

Locally, I use

```
find . | grep -E "$(uname -m)|$(dpkg --print-architecture)" | xargs -I{} cp -u {} dst/
```

to find and copy - but I'm not sure how to move this into scp.

My current attempt is stuck with:

```
scp user@host:dst/[*$(uname -m)*][*$(dpkg --print-architecture)*]
```

which finds nothing.

Comment: As I understand it, you want to grab *all* the files which **has** your print architecture in the filename ?

Answer (score 0):

After looking a bit - I found that [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28440217/3512538) can help me.

Using `rsync` I was able to copy exactly what I wanted:

```
py_version=$(python -V | cut -d' ' -f2 | tr -d ".")

rsync -am --include="*$(dpkg --print-architecture)*" --include="*${py_version:0:2}*$(uname -m)*" --exclude="*" user@host:dst .
```

Explanation:

- `py_version=$(python -V | cut -d' ' -f2 | tr -d ".")` gets me the 2 first version digits (e.g. 3.6.9 -> 36) which will help me pinpoint the wheel
- `--include="*$(dpkg --print-architecture)*"` will pinpoint the .deb
- `--include="*${py_version:0:2}*$(uname -m)*"` will pinpoint the wheel using architecture + python version
- `--exclude="*"` will remove everything else